# This 3D Cube is spinning differently in Chrome Vs Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone please let me know why the below codepen is breaking?It seems to run fine while running in Chrome, but not in Safari. I think it has something to do with the transform-origin in the CSS, but I'm not sure.

https://codepen.io/EKuhn/pen/WmXdJx

```css
.wrapper{
  margin: 180px;
  padding: 100px;
   -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  user-select:none;
  position: absolute;

}
  
#cube{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
 
  position: absolute;
  transform:rotate3d(1,1,1,90deg);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
 transform-origin:50% 50% -150px;
 

}
.side{
  border:0.2px solid #000;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:300px;
   transform-origin:50% 50% -150px;

}

#side1{
  transform:rotateY(0deg)
}

#side2{
  transform:rotateY(90deg)
}
#side3{
  transform:rotateY(-90deg)
}
#side4{
  transform:rotateX(90deg)
}
#side5{
  transform:rotateX(-90deg)
}
#side6{
  transform:rotateY(180deg)
}
```

Comment: what version of safari?

Comment: I'm using version 10.1.2 of Safari

Comment: It really looks like safari just isn't reading "transform-origin:50% 50% -150px;" Does anyone know a workaround?